# How to implement Biometric Authentication in a ReactJS Web Application

Tags: reactjs, django, mariadb, fingerprint, guacamole

I currently have a web application set up using ReactJS for the front-end, Django and Apache Guacamole for the back-end and MariaDB for the database. I also have a Secugen Hamster Plus Fingerprint Scanner which when plugged in to the computer, will be used for user authentication on the login page of the web application (using ReactJS).

Does anyone know how I can go about writing code to retrieve fingerprint images from the database to compare them with the user-inputted fingerprint when he attempts to login? I have been unsuccessful in finding any working examples or documentation for reference on the Internet.

Comment: Have you looked at https://secugen.com/products/webapi/? I just googled "Hamster Plus API".

Comment: Have you looked at [SecuGen Web API Manual](https://webapi.secugen.com/docs/SECUGEN_WEB_SERVICE_API_DOC.pdf)? I just googled "Hamster Plus output data types". There is also example which runs on localhost. Btw. _SecuGen WebAPI is free to use for up to 60 days per domain. After 60 days, you will need to purchase a License Key from SecuGen._ [source](https://secugen.com/request-free-software/)

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I have installed the WebAPI Client Application from the SecuGen website as well as the WebApi zip file containing the code for the API. However, I have no idea how to run it so that I can host the API pages on my localhost.